# Are there any genuine gers near Sydney?

Tags: australia, sydney, new-south-wales, weekends, gers

Are there any genuine gers (yurts) near Sydney which can be booked for accommodation?

Looking on [AirBNB](https://www.airbnb.com.au/s/New-South-Wales--Australia?type=yurt), I can see some exclusively timber-based constructions that are ger-themed, but not really the real thing, such as [The Yurt - treetops retreat](https://www.airbnb.com.au/rooms/273538), in New South Wales. And I can see some genuine gers, using canvas rather than entirely wood, in Victoria, such as [The Yurt Alpine Retreat King Valley](https://www.airbnb.com.au/rooms/1483865). There's a ger in the [Australian National University](http://www.canberratimes.com.au/act-news/canberra-life/ganggang-upmarket-mongolian-yurt-pops-up-at-the-anu-20160322-gnp0g4.html), but it's not for accommodation. [Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/here-are-australias-10-most-unusual-listings-on-airbnb-2015-5#yurt2) mentions various unusual accommodations, but the ones for gers are in Victoria.

It should ideally be accessible by a couple of hours' land transport (car, coach, or train) from Sydney.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There do not appear to be, not with your parameters, that it be a traditional structure and within a certain distance from Sydney.

Your options are limited to travelling a greater distance to those you've identified in Australia for the experience, or, should you be so inclined, purchasing one of your very own. [Suzie in Rosebank has this on offer](https://www.gumtree.com.au/s-ad/rosebank/miscellaneous-goods/mongolian-yurt/1144843751) this traditional ger/yurt, price negotiable.

[image]

[image]